# KMeans find inertia_ from GridSearchCV

Tags: python, k-means, grid-search

New to ML and learning how to use different algorithms.

Dataset is the SKLearn Iris Dataset

What I'm trying to determine is how to get inertia_ values and the best cluster value if I use GridSearchCV?  Can I even use GridSearchCV?

What I'm doing today (it works but if seems inefficient in comparison to using GridSearchCV)

This works, no issues

```
X = data.data

# Scale X
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

inertias = []

for i in range(1,20):
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    model.fit(scaled_X)
    inertias.append(model.inertia_)
inertias
```

I can even use Pipeline

```
inertias = []
for i in range(1,20):
    pipe = Pipeline([
        ('sc', StandardScaler()),
        ('kmeans', KMeans(n_clusters=i))
    ], verbose=True)


    pipe.fit(scaled_X)
    inertias.append(pipe.named_steps['kmeans'].inertia_)
inertias
```

With both methods above I can plot the inertias and find the best cluster value (which is 3).

But is there a way to use GridSearchCV to get a similar inertia value?

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('sc', StandardScaler()),
    ('kmeans', KMeans())
], verbose=True)

param_grid = {
    'kmeans__n_clusters':range(1,20)
}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, verbose=3)
grid.fit(scaled_X)

# What     
grid.best_params_
{'kmeans__n_clusters': 19}

grid.score(scaled_X)
-26.379283976769145

# What I would like is to be able to call something like grid.inertia_ or find a way to store the inertia_ values and call them from grid.
```

I can't rely on the `grid.best_params_` or the `grid.score(scaled_X)` because the results are inconsistent with the first 2 results.  Elbow method shows about 3 for the number of clusters which appears correct because this is the Iris flower dataset from SKLearn.

Is it possible to get the best cluster values from the GridSearchCV?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your loop strategy is not running [k-fold cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) which `GridSearchCV` does by default for `k=5` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)). You can get the test set mean inertia with `-1*GridSearchCV.cv_results_["mean_test_score"]`. Note the `-1`, we are turning this pseudo "reward" value back to a loss.